# Knockout-Validation - Date greater than another date

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-validation

I've been looking at the different methods of using knockout-validation to compare dates. I can't get it to work with my obervables in a validatedObservable object.

I need the validatedObservable for checking if the validation passed/ failed on the button click - it's my grouping of controls.

Here's my demo:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/knockout-2.3.0.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/knockout.validation.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/moment.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Name:</td>
            <td><input type="text" data-bind="value:contactForm().name" value="" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>From:</td>
            <td><input type="text" data-bind="value:contactForm().fromDate" value="" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>To:</td>
            <td><input type="text" data-bind="value:contactForm().toDate" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <button type="button" data-bind='click: submit'>Submit</button>
</form>
<script>

    ko.validation.init({
        messagesOnModified: false,
        parseInputAttributes: true,
        grouping: {
            deep: true
        }
    });

    var myViewModel = function () {
        var self = this;
        self.contactForm = ko.validatedObservable({
                name :ko.observable().extend({ required: true }),
                fromDate :ko.observable('2014-11-10').extend({ date: true }),
                toDate: ko.observable('2014-11-10').extend({date: true, min: this.fromDate })
            });
            submit = function () {
                console.log(this.contactForm.isValid())
            };
        };

        ko.applyBindings(new myViewModel());

</script>
```

I basically can't get the this line working:

```
toDate: ko.observable('2014-11-10').extend({date: true, min: this.fromDate })
```

anyone any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you're using `this` in an object literal creation (when you refer to `fromDate` in `toDate` declration), and upon constructing that object, `this` is still referring to the encapsulating function context (`myViewModel` in this case).

Try this instead (based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4616273)):

```
self.contactForm = ko.validatedObservable({
            name: ko.observable().extend({ required: true }),
            fromDate: ko.observable('2014-11-10').extend({ date: true }),
            toDate: ko.observable('2014-11-10'),
            init: function() {
                this.toDate = this.toDate.extend({date: true, min: this.fromDate});
                return this;
            }
        }.init());
```

Comment: Thank you for this, was at it for hours